# CodeIgniter login session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication

I'm new in CodeIgniter and I tried to create a login system on my website. When I try to enter on page Overview, it sends me on login page but after I put my correct email and password nothing happens.

**Login.php - controller**

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access
allowed');
     class Login extends CI_Controller {
      function __construct()
      {
        parent::__construct();
      }

      function index()
      {
        $this->load->helper(array('form'));
        $this->load->view('login');
      }

     }
    ?>
```

**Overview.php - controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Overview extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
 }

 function index()
 {
   if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
   {
     $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
     $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
     $this->load->view('overview', $data);
   }
   else
   {
     //If no session, redirect to login page
     redirect('login', 'refresh');
   }
 }

 function logout()
 {
   $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
   session_destroy();
   redirect('home', 'refresh');
 }

}

?>
```

**VerifyLogin.php - controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
 }

 function index()
 {
   //This method will have the credentials validation
   $this->load->library('form_validation');

   $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'E-mail', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

   if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
   {
     //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
     $this->load->view('login');
   }
   else
   {
     //Go to private area
     redirect('home', 'refresh');
   }

 }

 function check_database($password)
 {
   //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
   $username = $this->input->post('username');

   //query the database
   $result = $this->user->login($username, $password);

   if($result)
   {
     $sess_array = array();
     foreach($result as $row)
     {
       $sess_array = array(
         'id' => $row->id,
         'username' => $row->username
       );
       $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
     }
     return TRUE;
   }
   else
   {
     $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
     return false;
   }
 }
}
?>
```

**Login.php - views**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 well">
<form role="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="loginform">
<fieldset>
<legend>Login</legend>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="name">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required class="form-control" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="name">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Your Password" required class="form-control" />       
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" />
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
<span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($errormsg)) { echo $errormsg; } ?></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks and I hope somene will give me a solution.

Comment: Because your action link in form keeps posting to `index()` method in `Login` controller which only displays login form. Action link should post to `VerifyLogin` controller.

Comment: Your controller VerifyLogin.php should only have the first letter upper case Verifylogin.php and `class Verifylogin extends CI_Controller {`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I changed it and it does the same thing..

Comment: @TheDrot I don't really understand what I need to change.. I'm sorry, maybe you can tell me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you enter login page, the action will be "Login.php" because of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.

```
<form role="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="loginform">
```

> The $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] is a super global variable that returns the filename of the currently executing script.

You need to change the action to `VerifyLogin`, so when you submit form, the `index()` method in `Verifylogin.php` will execute.

```
<form role="form" action="VerifyLogin" method="post" name="loginform">
```

`xss_clean` is no longer a part of form validation so remove it. XSS cleaning should be used on output not input.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'E-mail', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|callback_check_database');
```

Comment: Thanks @TheDrot, everything worked but it redirect me on login page without errors instead on Overview page. I think the redirect is a problem..

Comment: @funkyz0r So change `redirect('home', 'refresh');` to `redirect('overview', 'refresh');` wherever you need to redirect to Overview page.

Comment: I changed that and nothing.. it drives me crazy

Comment: @funkyz0r Does `logged_in` array exist in session?

Comment: @funkyz0r Is Session library getting autoloaded? Check application/config/autoload.php file and look at `$autoload['libraries']` array.

Comment: $autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','form_validation');

Comment: @funkyz0r Then the only thing I can think of is that query is always returning false. You should `var_dump($result); die();` in `check_database()` method to see if query is working properly.

Comment: same thing.. stays on Login page. It doesn't show the query.

Comment: @funkyz0r Jesus christ... ok you need to remove `xss_clean` from validation rules because that function is not anymore a part of form validation. Remove that and it will work.